# React-router Async redirect in willTransitionTo

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

Using React, React-Router (I'm using v0.12), and Reflux, I'm having trouble getting an async redirect in willTransitionTo working (this code lies in the login component, but if you're already logged in, it should send you to 'home'). Here's the code:

```
statics : {
  willTransitionTo : function(transition, params, query, callback) {
    // cut out other logic if flux store is already set for sake of brevity
    UserStore.listen(userData => {
      if (userData.loggedInStatus === 'completed' && !_.isEmpty(userData.loggedInUser)) {
        return transition.redirect('home');
      }
      callback();
    });
  }
},
```

that Login component doesn't render, but neither does the "home" component (the URL also doesn't change).

Comment: Have you tried to also call callback after calling transition.redirect('home'), why are you returning the function call btw?